# Pandas scatterplot

Tags: pandas, scatter-plot

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and rows. One of the columns is filled with either a '6' or '8'.
I need to create a scatterplot with only the rows that contain '8'.
Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: `df[df['your_column_name']==8]` gives you all the rows with `8`.

Comment: Thanks Quang. Can you tell me how do i make a scatterplot with just that data? Without creating a seperate dataframe.

Comment: chain that with `.plot.scatter(x='x_col', y='y_col')`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks heaps Quang :)